# Python Chatbot: NameError: name 'leave' is not defined

Tags: python

Im trying to create a simple Chatbot in python:

```
import random

greetings = ["Yo,", "Hello,", "Howdy,", "Greetings,"]

print(random.choice(greetings))
print("im OCB-1")

userName = input("What is your name?")
print("Nice to meet you, " + userName + "!")
print("")

if userName == "OCB-1":
  print ("Wait, you bastar-")
  exit()
else:
  print("I hope you are having a great day!")

print("List of activites:")
print("")
print("Talk about books")
print("")
activity = input("What would you want to do?")

if activity == "Talk about books":
  print ("Sure, what book do you want to talk about? I know")
  print("Harry Potter")
  bookActivity = input(":")
else:
  print("")
  print("Unexpected Error: Activity not found (Program recognizes capital and small letters)")
  exit()
  
if bookActivity == "Harry Potter":
  print("")
  bookrateHarryPotter = input("How would you rate Harry Potter, -/10 ?")
else:
  print("")
  print("Unexpected Error: Book not found (Program recognizes capital and small letters)")
  exit()
  
  if bookrateHarryPotter(1/10, 2/10, 3/10, 4/10, 5/10, 6/10, 7/10, 8/10, 9/10, 10/10,):
    print("Nice, I think I would rate it 8/10 :).")
    print("")
    
    out = input("Do you want to go back to activites or leave?")
    out = out.lower()
  while (out != "leave"):
    
   leave = input("In this session I learned: Your Harry Potter book rate which is " + bookrateHarryPotter + ". Are you sure you want to leave? y/n")

if leave == "y":
    print("Killing session...")
    exit()
else:
  print("Unexpected Error: couldnt find y")
  print("")
  
if leave == "n":
    print("Thank you...")
    print("I will print list of Activites")
    print("List of activites:")
    print("")
    print("Talk about books")
    print("")
    activity = input("What would you want to do?")
    print("")
else:
  print("Unexpected Error: couldnt find n")
  print("")
```

but it is failing on line: `if leave == "y":`

can someone help please?

im new to python...

```
Greetings,
im OCB-1
What is your name?
Oli
Nice to meet you, Oli!

I hope you are having a great day!
List of activites:

Talk about books

What would you want to do?
Talk about books
Sure, what book do you want to talk about? I know
Harry Potter
:
Harry Potter

How would you rate Harry Potter, -/10 ?
5/10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 51, in <module>
    if leave == "y":
NameError: name 'leave' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You only define `leave` when `if bookActivity == "Harry Potter":` returns `False`. So, if that `if` statement was `True`, `leave` will not be defined, thus leading to the error. You have to make sure `leave` is defined beforehand regardless.

If you use a decent IDE to edit your code, it will warn you of mistakes like this without you even having to run the code. [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is free and is really great, I highly recommend it.

Comment: Can you please edit the code and send it, I dont understand English im from Slovakia

Comment: At the top of the file, at the beginning of your code, put in the line `leave = "n"`.